# Change position of facet strip text

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to have strip and their texts for each facet on the right side of y axis instead of the top of x axis in ggplot2 in R.

I tried `theme**(strip.placement = c("right"))`** after removing the strip and their texts from top of the x axis by using **`theme(strip.text = element_blank(), strip.background = element_blank())+`**

Strip texts were disappeared from the top but I am not able to place them on the right side of the y axis.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's easier to help if you [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format, all the relevant code and any error messages.

Comment: You don’t need to remove the strips from the top. i.e., remove `theme(strip.text = element_blank(), strip.background = element_blank())` and try it with just `theme(strip.placement = "right")`.

Comment: Hi @zephryl, thanks for responding. I tried this but the strips are still on the top of the x axis.

Comment: Ok - as @neilfws said, we’d need to see more of a reproducible example to troubleshoot further.

Comment: Image of code is attached in the question. Please have a look @zephryl

Comment: The `facet_wrap()` function has a `strip.position` argument that you can use to change the strip from at the top to the right.